# Unable to get the records using fetch in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have creted the blogs API using following code:

```
const fs = require('fs');  

export default async function handler(req, res) 
{
  let blogs = [];
  try 
  {
    let files=  fs.readdirSync('blogdata');
    files.forEach((file)=>{
      let content =  fs.readFileSync('blogdata/'+file,'utf-8');
      blogs.push(JSON.parse(content));
    });
    res.status(200).json({blogs})
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

When I am trying to get the data with following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function  Blogs()  
{
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('* useEffect *');
    
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/blogs')
    .then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((json)=>{ 
      console.log('json ',json);
      setBlogs(json);      
    })

  },[]);

  return (
    <>
    <div>blogs</div>
    
    {blogs.length > 0 ? (
      blogs.map((blog, index) => 
      {
        <p>blog.title</p>
      })
    ): 
    (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    )}
    </>
  )
}
```

then it is always showing loading. For debugging, I have used the console log and the console.log('json ',json); is showing data but is not papulate into the return section. Thanks in advance!

Even I have try to pass static conetnt from api then still showing the same.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  If the AJAX call is made but the server never returns a response, what debugging have you done on the server-side code?  Does the server console show any errors?

Comment: Yes request is working fine and console is not showing any error. Please check the following videos for better understanding: https://nimb.ws/Tnl2c4 and  
 https://nimb.ws/xwJhom

Comment: “Request is working fine” doesn’t really describe a problem.  And we’re not here to watch videos, relevant information about the problem belongs here in the question.  What is the exact observed response data from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you are sending from the API route is not an array but on object containing the array.

```js
// change this
res.status(200).json({blogs})

// to this
res.status(200).json(blogs)
```

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks! . One more query please. I am new to react. Please check these videos https://nimb.ws/Tnl2c4 and https://nimb.ws/xwJhom . You can notice that useEffect is running twice. Even I have checked on the fresh app too and it is running twice.

Comment: That is because of strict mode. You can read more about it [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode).